# How do I portably and reliably unblock/interrupt `recv` on a UDP socket from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, udp, portability

## Problem

There is a thread running `recv` on a blocking UDP socket in a loop. We need to stop that thread and close that socket.

Example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> the_socket;

void threadf() {
    for(;;) {
        char c;
        int ret = recv(the_socket, &c, 1, 0);
        if(ret == 0 || ret == -1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    close(the_socket);
}

int main() {
    the_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    std::thread *t = new std::thread(threadf);
    usleep(200000);
    shutdown(the_socket, SHUT_RDWR); // ENOTCONN
    t->join();
    delete t;
    return 0;
}
```

Description:

1. It creates UDP socket
2. It starts another thread that receives packets from that socket, synchronously.
3. The main thread decides it's time to stop. `delete t` is a bad idea. `close(the_socket)` does not unblock the neighbouring thread. But `shutdown`, although itself failing, does the job:

```
[pid 22289] nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=200000000},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 22290] <... set_robust_list resumed> ) = 0
[pid 22290] recvfrom(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 22289] <... nanosleep resumed> NULL) = 0
[pid 22289] shutdown(3, SHUT_RDWR)      = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[pid 22290] <... recvfrom resumed> "", 1, 0, NULL, NULL) = 0
```

## Questions

- <s>How portable and reliable is this scheme?</s> No, not portable at all.
- <s>Is exact behaviour of `shutdown` in multi-threaded environment documented somewhere?</s> No.
- <s>Is effect of `shutdown` on non-connected/UDP sockets documented somewhere?</s> No.
- Can something else be done to a socket to interrupt `recv` on neighbouring thread reliably and portably?

---

**Update**: Seems like it fails on Mac. `close` however does works there...

Comment: `SO_RCVTIMEO` while another thread is receiving also does not do what I mean.

Comment: You would have to set `SO_RCVTIMEO` before starting a blocking read (assuming the platform supports it in the first place - not all do). However, UDP is being used, so you could just `sendto()` a private UDP packet to the listening port to wake up the blocking `recv()` (you should be using `recvfrom()` instead, since you are not using `connect()` to statically associate the socket with a peer IP/port so `recv()` can filter packets), then the reading thread is free to terminate itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thanks. Already explored the approach and it seems to be working, although cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given only the UDP socket by itself, the only truly portable options to wake up the thread are to either:

1. switch the socket to non-blocking mode, and then have the thread use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to detect when inbound packets are ready to be read from the socket.  That way, you can specify a timeout on each wait, and the thread can check for termination in between waits.
2. use `sendto()` to send a private UDP packet to the socket's listening port to wake up a blocking `recv()`/`recvfrom()` call, then the thread will be free to check for termination. Just note that this will not work if you use `connect()` to statically associate the UDP socket with a peer IP/port, as doing so restricts `recv()`/`recvfrom()` from receiving any packets from other sources.  That is not the case in the example you provided, but it is something you should be aware of.

On many platforms, you can use a blocking read timeout via `setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)`, then you can specify a timeout on each read, and the thread can check for termination in between reads.  But not all platforms support `SO_RCVTIMEO`.

Otherwise, you can open a second UDP socket or pipe, and have the thread use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to monitor it alongside the main UDP socket at the same time.  Don't call `recv()`/`recvfrom()` on the main socket unless there is actually something to read from it.  Connect/send to the second pipe/socket when you want to wake up the thread.

Comment: Is empty (0-length) datagram a good idea for such private packet?

Comment: @Vi.: Yes, that is perfectly fine, and commonly done in this situation. Just make sure your code that processes received packets is ready to handle empty data, if you don't terminate the thread beforehand.

Comment: You left out (3) use a blocking-mode  read timeout, or do you consider that not truly portable? I seem to remember Solaris of all things doesn't support it.

Comment: @EJP: I left that out on purpose because it is not a 100% portable solution, as not all platforms support it. But I have added it anyway, since many of the more commonly used platforms do support it.

Comment: I've never used one that didn't, and I did a ton of multi-platform networking stuff 25 years ago, but I discovered that Solaris doesn't by reading the Java native source code for Solaris one day in an idle moment. If the `Socket`'s read timeout isn't zero they have to do a `select()`. Amazing.